# MySQL and PHP One to Many Return Data in Single Row, Multiple Columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have been learning PHP and MySQL for a project and I am struggling with this part. For simplicity sake, I will only list the relevant fields (actually many more in real db) let's say I have 3 tables.

```
Table1
---------------------
Index | Name | email
1     | Rob  | rob@email.com
2     | Kevin| kevin@email.com
3     | Amy  | amy@email.com

Table2
------------------------
id    | Info | Submitted
1     | Blah | 0
2     | Yada | 1

Table 3
-------------------------
id    | Goal |Submitted
1     | 1    | 1
1     | 2    | 1
1     | 3    | 1
1     | 4    | 0
1     | 5    | 0
3     | 1    | 0
3     | 3    | 1
3     | 4    | 1
```

So, Table1 holds user information and is kinda the main table

Table2 the user inputs some data in a field and then submits for approval when ready. (I will be using the value of Submitted for functions later)
If the user has not submitted the info, there is not record. This is a 1 to 1 with Table1

Table3 The user inputs information for 5 goals. At any given time there could be 0 to max 5 goals entered for a user. The Submitted is the same for later processing. This table is Many to one with Table1. The Goal field literally shows the number 1 through 5, there is a separate field that holds the goal text, just not needed in this example.

Desired output is HTML table

```
Name   |  email          | info |Goal1|Goal2|Goal3|Goal4|Goal5|
Rob    | rob@email.com   | Blah |   1 |   2 |  3  |  4  |  5  |
Kevin  | kevin@email.com | Yada |     |     |     |     |     |              
Amy    | amy@email.com   |      |   1 |     |  3  |  4  |     |
```

Not sure if the blanks are considered NULL or something else as they do not exist in the DB. I would like to put something in the field like an *.  Basically the Submitted will be used for code to make the fields hyper links, so they need to be part of the query, just not in the table display, but if it would help, it can be displayed.

```
 Name   |  email          | info |Goal1|Goal2|Goal3|Goal4|Goal5|
 Rob    | rob@email.com   | Blah |   1 |   2 |  3  |  4  |  5  |
 Kevin  | kevin@email.com | Yada |   * |   * |  *  |  *  |  *  |
 Amy    | amy@email.com   |   *  |   1 |  *  |  3  |  4  |  *  |
```

I am using a query with left joins and group_concat, but that is not working well with the non existent data, and I cannot figure out how to include the Submitted field without doing some crazy concatenation, then pulling in all apart to put in the HTML fields.

I can include some code, but it might be hard to follow as there are lots of variables being used.

The best I have gotten out using only table1 and table3:
Rob 1,2,3,4,5
Kevin
Amy 1,3,4

With the records that have not been entered not be accounted for, it makes it near impossible to turn the data string into a table.  If I can get something showing for every position, even if it does not exist yet, I do know how to make it into the html table.

I hope this makes sense and someone can help me with this.

Comment: there are too many solutions to this currently.  can you post your main query or queries and or use pseudo code to explain where you think you have a specific question?

Comment: what you tried? share your main sql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated that you have at most 5 goals. The best possible option is to use following query.

```
SELECT t1.Name,t1.email
,CASE WHEN t2.Info IS NULL THEN * ELSE t2.Info END as Info
,CASE WHEN g1.Goal IS NULL THEN * ELSE g1.Goal END as Goal1
,CASE WHEN g2.Goal IS NULL THEN * ELSE g2.Goal END as Goal2
,CASE WHEN g3.Goal IS NULL THEN * ELSE g3.Goal END as Goal3
,CASE WHEN g4.Goal IS NULL THEN * ELSE g4.Goal END as Goal4
,CASE WHEN g5.Goal IS NULL THEN * ELSE g5.Goal END as Goal5
FROM Table1 as t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 as t2 ON t2.id = t1.Index
    LEFT JOIN Table3 as g1 ON g1.id = t1.Index AND g1.Goal=1
    LEFT JOIN Table3 as g2 ON g2.id = t1.Index AND g2.Goal=2
    LEFT JOIN Table3 as g3 ON g3.id = t1.Index AND g3.Goal=3
    LEFT JOIN Table3 as g4 ON g4.id = t1.Index AND g4.Goal=4
    LEFT JOIN Table3 as g5 ON g5.id = t1.Index AND g5.Goal=5
```

Comment: Thank you! This is working great. Just for reference, the * must be quoted to work, so '*'. Now, a question about the Submitted field. For each goal, if it was submitted(Submitted value = 1), how could I replace the goal number with an 'S'?

Comment: I was able to figure out how to use the value of submitted to change the data shown. A sample line is below:

    ,CASE WHEN g1.Goal IS NULL THEN '*' WHEN g1.Submitted = 1 Then 'S' ELSE g1.Goal END as Goal1

Answer (score 0):

You will want to JOIN each of the tables together, and GROUP BY the user.

One way of handling the goals would be to display it as one column, containing all goals.

This should help you get started:

```
SELECT name, 
       email, 
       info, 
       <LOGIC> as goals
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table2.user_id = table1.id
JOIN table3 ON table3.user_id = table1.id
GROUP BY name
```

The logic that you use for the goals column could be created with a mixture of CASE and CONCAT (if a goal is defined, concatenate it into a string, and display that string as the final value of goals).

Comment: where you getting column name is `goal1, goal2, goal3`